# Browsing method documentation consumes 4 quota units per page

Tags: support, documentation, quota

Is it my imagination (scratch that, it's definitely not), or does simply browsing method doc pages (without using the *"Run"* function) consume quota?

From Bash using `httpie` and `jq` (on a private, non-shared IP):

```
$ http "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1648771200&order=asc&sort=creation&site=askubuntu&pagesize=100&page=1" | jq ".quota_remaining"
164
# Repeat again
$ http "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1648771200&order=asc&sort=creation&site=askubuntu&pagesize=100&page=1" | jq ".quota_remaining"
163
```

Go browse the [/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers) method doc in the browser.  Then [/answers/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids).

Then, again:

```
$ http "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions?fromdate=1648771200&order=asc&sort=creation&site=askubuntu&pagesize=100&page=1" | jq ".quota_remaining"
154
```

Each doc (method) page hit seems to consume 4 quota units.

On the other hand, pages like [Write Access](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write) do not drain quota.

This appears to be because the *"Try it"* on each method page makes a call to `/sites` to retrieve the list of possible SE sites, whether or not the *"Try it"* feature is even used.

Is this expected?  I didn't find anything here with the following searches:

- [quota method](https://stackapps.com/search?q=quota+method)
- [quota doc](https://stackapps.com/search?q=quota+doc)
- [quota help](https://stackapps.com/search?q=quota+help)

Sure, 4 per page isn't much if you've registered for a key and have upped the quota to 10,000, but for new users starting out browsing the doc (an obvious first step), the unkeyed 300 quota limit can be rather quickly run down just *browsing* the doc.

Should this be considered a "bug"?  Could/should it be fixed either by:

- An easy, low-hanging change to *"Try it"* to retrieve 1000 sites at a time to reduce this to single API call?  (As @Glorfindel points out in the comments, `/sites` already allows a pagesize of 1000 anyway, but *"Try it"* only retrieves 100 at a time.
- (The real fix, I believe) Having *"Try it"* not populate the Site list until the user attempts to *"Edit"*/change the default site from Stack Overflow to something else (if they even need to)
- Not subtract `/sites` calls from the unkeyed quota? (from @Glorfindel comment below)
- (Fallback) Exempting `/sites` from the quota?  This shouldn't be an issue, since it's normally going to be a rather rare call, I would think, for most apps.  And existing 30 calls/second limits should still be in place.

Comment: FWIW, `/sites` *already* has a page size exception: with `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pageSize=1000` you'll get all sites at once.

Comment: @Glorfindel Well that's nice - At least the *"Try it"* feature could be (easily) changed to utilize that to cut down the number of requests from 4 to 1.

Comment: It already uses the Documentation's own key; another way to solve it would be to not subtract requests with a key from a user's 'generic' 300/day quota.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, that would work as well.  It still subtracts quota on my own keyed requests as well, of course, but with the higher limit that's not (shouldn't be) a problem.